# Using Flickr to Enable Images on a Site

Tags: php, photo, flickr, phpflickr

Has anyone had success using Flickr to embed images that users can upload to my site, but that are hosted on Flickr?

Is something like this possible?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: People should be careful with this distinction: you can upload your own photos to Flickr.  But you can not upload your users photos to your company's account.  So if you have users uploading photos, Flickr might not be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flikr upload API:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

Have them upload their photos to your site, you can crop it or re-size it programatically with GD or imagemagick as needed, then use the flikr upload API to put it on your flickr account, then delete the original to save space, then embed it on the site.

This will save space for you. While also preventing your users from needing to get an account on another site, or having to leave your site to post photos, or figuring out how to link them back.